# assigning a query result to a variable is always null sql

Tags: sql, count, exec

I have written the following script in sql and @TotalTabs is always returning null?

```
DECLARE @TotalTabs NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cmd = ' Select count(*) from(select distinct COutputData_3_autosampler position, COutputData_3_Sequence_Number from '
    + @temp_table_afterpivot_SegRpt + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @TotalTabs, N'@TotalTabs nvarchar out', @TotalTabs OUT  

SELECT  @TotalTabs
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are executing the @TotalTabs as the SQL when you should be executing @cmd.  In fact your @cmd is never used anywhere.

```
Select count(*) from (select distinct COutputData_3_autosampler, position, COutputData_3_Sequence_Number from '
+ @temp_table_afterpivot_SegRpt + ') AS TT'
```

You are missing a comma after position.  I assume all 3 columns are in the @temp_table_afterpivot_SeqRpt?

Comment: Thanks. I have now updated to run @cmd, then again. I get an error Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: your SQL is not correct, I will post on this answer what I "think" you want.  missing a comma

Comment: Thanks. There are only two columns I have changed to the following  'Select count(*) from(select distinct [COutputData_3_autosampler position], COutputData_3_Sequence_Number from ' +
@temp_table_afterpivot_SegRpt + ')'. I still get the same error. yes both these columns are present in the temporary table.

Comment: i think i see the problem, is the @temp_table_afterpivot_SeqRpt a TABLE variable or a variable with the name of the table, it would help to post the source of all variables.

Comment: It is the name of the temporary table table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works now, see answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone.  I have found the issue, the script requires an alias.

declare @TotalTabs nvarchar (30)
declare @cmd nvarchar (max)
set @cmd = 'Select count(*) from (select distinct [COutputData_3_AutoSampler Position], COutputData_3_Sequence_Number from '
+ @temp_table_afterpivot_SegRpt + ') as tt'
exec sp_executesql @cmd, N'@TotalTabs nvarchar out', @TotalTabs out

select @TotalTabs as TotalTabs